# Keras.Model.Sequential for AlexNet gives the following error

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement AlexNet Architecture for CNN. The code uses the CiFAR-10 dataset to identify and label various images under different categories. It is based on  the following link:

https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-alexnet-cnn-architecture-using-tensorflow-2-0-and-keras-2113e090ad98

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import time

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

CLASS_NAMES= ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

validation_images, validation_labels = train_images[:5000], train_labels[:5000]
train_images, train_labels = train_images[5000:], train_labels[5000:]

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
validation_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation_images, validation_labels))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
#for i, (image, label) in enumerate(train_ds.take(5)):
 #   ax = plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
  #  plt.imshow(image)
   # plt.title(CLASS_NAMES[label.numpy()[0]])
    #plt.axis('off')
    
    
def process_images(image, label):
    # Normalize images to have a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1
    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
    # Resize images from 32x32 to 277x277
    image = tf.image.resize(image,(227,227))
    return image, label

train_ds_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(train_ds).numpy()
test_ds_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(test_ds).numpy()
validation_ds_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(validation_ds).numpy()
print("Training data size:", train_ds_size)
print("Test data size:", test_ds_size)
print("Validation data size:", validation_ds_size)

train_ds = (train_ds
                  .map(process_images)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=train_ds_size)
                  .batch(batch_size=32, drop_remainder=True))
test_ds = (test_ds
                  .map(process_images)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=train_ds_size)
                  .batch(batch_size=32, drop_remainder=True))
validation_ds = (validation_ds
                  .map(process_images)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=train_ds_size)
                  .batch(batch_size=32, drop_remainder=True))

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), activation='relu', input_shape=(227,227,3), data_format='channels_first'),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation='relu', padding="same"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

root_logdir = os.path.join(os.curdir, "logs\\fit\\")
def get_run_logdir():
    run_id = time.strftime("run_%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")
    return os.path.join(root_logdir, run_id)
run_logdir = get_run_logdir()
tensorboard_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(run_logdir)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(train_ds,
          epochs=50,
          validation_data=validation_ds,
          validation_freq=1,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_14299/3484163785.py in <cell line: 53>()
     51                   .batch(batch_size=32, drop_remainder=True))
     52 
---> 53 model = keras.models.Sequential([
     54     keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), activation='relu', input_shape=(227,227,3), data_format='channels_first'),
     55     keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in compute_output_shape(self, input_shape)
    300 
    301     except ValueError:
--> 302       raise ValueError(
    303           f'One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 '
    304           f'due to downsampling in {self.name}. Consider '

ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv2d_40. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 227, 227, 3] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.
```

*Can somebody help me to solve this?*

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of `data_format='channels_first'`?

Comment: I actually didn't use it at first and even after using it, yielded the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement AlexNet with TensorFlow following this [repo](https://github.com/Eduardo-RP/Pretrained-AlexNet-TensorFlow-with-Weights). The architecture can be loaded easily with keras and it has the pretrained weights of ImageNet. You can merge the code above with the implementation from the repo an train the model AlexNet. Take in account that the input size of the image must be (224,224).